# Login takes away the slug from my URL

Tags: cakephp

I'm working Cake 2.1.3, and the routes.php file, everything worked fine except the login management, for example I want my url be as follows:

http://mysite.com/companyx/users/login

where companyx is the slug, however when you run that url in the browser is as follows:

http://mysite.com/users/login

In this file routes.php I have defined as follows:

```
Router::connect(
        '/:slug/users/login', // E.g. /companyx/users/login
        array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), array(
        // order matters
        'pass' => array('slug')
        )
    );
```

With other controllers I have no problems such as:

```
Router::connect(
        '/:slug/users', // E.g. /companyx/users 
        array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'), array(
        // order matters
        'pass' => array('slug')
        )
    );
```

Best Regards ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP has a default login action defined in the AuthComponent. (line 171)

```
 /**
  * A URL (defined as a string or array) to the controller action that handles
  * logins.  Defaults to `/users/login`
  *
  * @var mixed
  */
public $loginAction = array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'login',
    'plugin' => null
);
```

You can override this action with the beforeFilter in your own UsersController.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for you answer. I solved this case this way:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
     if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Auth->loginAction = 'this is:slug/users/login/';
     }
}
```

Where "this is slug", should be the slug.

Best Regards.